# What happenned to the 'Selected' property of the ListItem?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm in the process of creating a submission form that generates a PDF through ASP with back end VB and iTextSharp. Some of the questions are CheckBoxLists where multiple values can be selected and I need to keep track of which ones are selected by the user so certain triggers can happen upon PDF generation. From my research, I would think it would be as simple as checking the Selected property of each ListItem in the given CheckBoxList like so:

```
Public Sub getCheckBoxValues(checkboxlist As CheckBoxList)
    Dim strchklist As String
    Dim testItems As New List(Of ListItem)

    For Each li As ListItem In checkboxlist.Items
        If li.Selected Then
            'insert code here (adding to List for checks in this case)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

However in trying to run and work with it (in VS 2017), I keep getting an error that states "'Selected' is not a member of 'ListItem'" which makes no sense to me. Every source that I've found through ASP Snippets, Asp Forums, and other sources etc. gives me every indication that this property should still exist.

Is there something that I'm not aware of or another method, property, or solution out there that does what I'm trying to do that I'm not aware of? I would love some assistance and guidance on this.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Right click `ListItem` and select `Go to definition`. Check if it points to the correct type (`System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem` and also check if the `Selected` is shown as a member of this type). Come back with your findings.

Comment: AH.....I see it. It was pointing to the ITextSharp ListItem instead of the one I thought. Good check....thank you very much!